# How to specify a template for a Snippet in a StreamField when using SnippetChooserBlock

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to use a snippet in a StreamField:

```
@register_snippet
class Advert(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.text

class MyPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([('Snippet', SnippetChooserBlock(
                        target_model='web.Advert')])
```

my_page.html:

```
{% for block in page.body %}
    {% include_block block %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, when rendering the `Advert` it renders only the `str` representation of `self.text`. How can I specify a template layout for the snippet block, e.g. like a `StructBlock`?

**There is no documentation for SnippetChooserBlock.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all block types, `SnippetChooserBlock` [accepts a `template` argument](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#per-block-templates) that specifies the path to a template to render for that block:

```
class MyPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([('Snippet', SnippetChooserBlock(
                        target_model='web.Advert', template='blocks/advert.html')])
```

Within that template, the snippet instance is available as the variable `value`:

```
<div class="advert">
    <a href="{{ value.url }}">{{ value.text }}</a>
</div>
```